# Browserify build fails with local version of an npm module in my package.json dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify

I've managed to setup a `package.json` and build my app's dependencies into a bundle using `browserify`, however, when I try and switch out one of the dependencies for a forked local copy the build fails.

This works and installs the upstream version (omitting the other modules):

```
"dependencies": {"react-bootstrap": "0.13.0"}
```

A local path to my fork fails:

```
"dependencies": {"react-bootstrap": "/home/tom/dev/react-bootstrap/"}
```

As does using `npm link`, which seems to be the "correct" way of managing a local version with minimal hassle.

Finally, using the git url to my fork also fails:

```
"dependencies": {"react-bootstrap": "git://github.com/tompaton/react-bootstrap.git"}
```

I tried updating the `package.json` in the `react-bootstrap` module so the repository url pointed to `tompaton/react-bootstrap` but that didn't make any difference.

The error message I'm getting is not shedding any light on the situation:

```
(cycles)tom@neon:~/dev/flask_projects/cycles!$ npm run build

> Cycles@1.0.0 build /home/tom/dev/flask_projects/cycles
> browserify -r react-bootstrap -o static/lib-runtime.js

Error: Cannot find module 'react-bootstrap' from '/home/tom/dev/flask_projects/cycles'
    at /home/tom/dev/flask_projects/cycles/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:50:17
    at process (/home/tom/dev/flask_projects/cycles/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:119:43)
    at /home/tom/dev/flask_projects/cycles/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:128:21
    at load (/home/tom/dev/flask_projects/cycles/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:60:43)
    at /home/tom/dev/flask_projects/cycles/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:66:22
    at /home/tom/dev/flask_projects/cycles/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:21:47
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)

npm ERR! Cycles@1.0.0 build: `browserify -r react-bootstrap -o static/lib-runtime.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the Cycles@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the Cycles package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     browserify -r react-bootstrap -o static/lib-runtime.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls Cycles
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-43-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build-runtime"
npm ERR! cwd /home/tom/dev/flask_projects/cycles
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tom/dev/flask_projects/cycles/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

`/home/tom/dev/flask_projects/cycles/npm-debug.log` has the same information.

The `node_modules` folder looks like:

```
(cycles)tom@neon:~/dev/flask_projects/cycles!$ ls -al node_modules/react-bootstrap/
total 64
drwxrwxr-x  7 tom tom 4096 Dec 16 22:00 .
drwxrwxr-x 14 tom tom 4096 Dec 16 22:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 tom tom 4096 Dec 16 22:00 docs
-rw-r--r--  1 tom tom 3886 Dec 16 22:00 Gruntfile.js
drwxr-xr-x  3 tom tom 4096 Dec 16 22:00 ie8
-rw-r--r--  1 tom tom  228 Dec 16 22:00 .jshintrc
-rw-r--r--  1 tom tom  425 Dec 16 22:00 karma.ci.js
-rw-r--r--  1 tom tom  390 Dec 16 22:00 karma.dev.js
-rw-r--r--  1 tom tom 1123 Dec 16 22:00 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 tom tom  146 Dec 16 22:00 .npmignore
-rw-r--r--  1 tom tom 3596 Dec 16 22:00 package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 tom tom 1345 Dec 16 22:00 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  3 tom tom 4096 Dec 16 22:00 src
drwxr-xr-x  3 tom tom 4096 Dec 16 22:00 test
drwxr-xr-x  5 tom tom 4096 Dec 16 22:00 tools
-rw-r--r--  1 tom tom   37 Dec 16 22:00 .travis.yml
```

So `npm install` has downloaded the right version and the permissions are fine.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this? or at least to point me to better information on what the actual error is?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? I want to use `npm link` to make the path of the tests shorter: `x = require("../../../x")` -> `x = require("x")`. Do you think it is possible to solve this with `npm link` in a way which is browserify compatible? (I asked the question here, if you want to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446269/how-to-avoid-long-relative-paths-with-jasmine-in-different-environme )

Comment: no adequate solution to date. what i did was to install the upstream version using `npm install react-bootstrap` then manually copy the changed files from my local build folder into the `node_modules/react-bootstrap` folder.  that meant that my browserified lib-runtime.js had my copy of the files, but obviously it's not the right way to do it or an easy option to maintain.

Comment: Did you try symlink and NODE_PATH? People suggested those to me. (I am working on other issues now, so I have not had the time to check them yet.)

Comment: You should give a try adding your forked repo's parent directory to `NODE_PATH`. By me it solved the problem. Afaik NODE_PATH is supported by browserify, while npm link may not. I don't know, I am new to the topic... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Run `browserify` or your `gulp` task with `NODE_PATH=./node_modules` like so:

`NODE_PATH=./node_modules gulp scripts`

That will tell `node-resolve` and by extension, `browserify` to use that local folder to resolve all its dependencies.