# How to avoid long relative paths (../../../) with jasmine in different environments?

Tags: node.js, testing, jasmine, karma-runner, browserify

I am currently developing a project, which I want to test in different environments - including node.js and different browsers with karma/selenium - to avoid compatibility issues. (I think I will use browserify in browsers, but I am not familiar with it yet.)

I have a nested testing directory, something like this:

```
repo/
- project.js
- project.my.module.js
- spec/
-- helpers/
--- a.jasmine.helper.js
-- support/
--- jasmine.json
-- project.my.module/
--- ModuleClass.spec.js
-- project.MyClass.spec.js
-- project.OtherClass.spec.js
```

Currently I tested the project only with jasmine-npm (which is jasmine 2.2 for node.js). By testing the working directory is the `repo/`, where I run `node.exe` with `jasmine.js`. The `jasmine.js` loads the `jasmine.json`:

```
{
  "spec_dir": "spec",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*[sS]pec.js"
  ],
  "helpers": [
    "helpers/**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

Now I have 2 problems here.

- How can I avoid the long relative paths by require, for example `require("../../project.my.module.js")` in the `ModuleClass.spec.js` file? (I would rather use a short constant name, like I can do by symlink.)
- How can I do this in a way that is compatible with running the same test files in different browsers? (I want to keep the commonjs module definitions by the tests.)

I checked some tutorials about node.js, and it seems like I have two options. I can use the `package.json` (with some magic config options unknown to me), or I can move the files I want to load, to the `node_modules/` (which I am sure I won't do). I am open for suggestions, because I can't see how it is possible to solve this issue...

**edit:**

The [karma-browserify](https://github.com/nikku/karma-browserify) appears to solve the testing problem, probably I have to add a jasmine for browser, but that's okay. I don't have to change the commonjs module definitions by the tests. So it is possible to test both in node.js and the browser with the long paths.

**edit2:**

I ended up adding the parent dir of my repo to NODE_PATH. This way I can require every project I am currently developing.

Comment: Haha, I guess, I am asking impossible again... :D

Comment: How about using [`NODE_PATH`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders)? Or putting everything in a `node_modules`?

Comment: @laggingreflex I don't want to change the directory structure. I'll check NODE_PATH asap.

Comment: @laggingreflex Browserify appears to support `NODE_PATH`: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/726 . I found another possible solution: `npm link` I'll investigate that either...

Comment: @laggingreflex If understand well `NODE_PATH` environment variable is about changing the path what node uses to require the 3rd party modules. I like to install modules with npm globally, and have my projects in a directory structure: `/projects/{project-name}/` for many years, which I don't want to change either. So it is out of option, or I misunderstood something.

Comment: `require('any-module')` will look for `any-module` in `./node_modules` (as ususal) **and** in paths specified in `NODE_PATH`. If I understand your requirement, you'd want to set `/projects/` in `NODE_PATH` so that you could `require('project-name')`. Actually typing this out I think I may have misunderstood you. What you want is probably `npm link`, yes?

Comment: @laggingreflex Nope, what I want is `require('project-name')` in my test files, which are under the spec folder in the project repo. So you say that with the NODE_PATH I will be able to use both the ~inf3rno/node_modules/ and the projects/ as module sources? That would be great!

Comment: @laggingreflex The `NODE_PATH` works perfectly. I haven't tried with browserify yet, but afaik. browserify supports it. Thanks! How to give points? :D

Comment: I would turn it into an answer but I think at this point you'd be in a far better position to create a much more detailed answer, explaining why it actually ended up working in your case, and why other things did not etc, and mark that as accepted. I'm just glad it worked out for you. :)

Comment: @laggingreflex Okay, then I accept the other answer, and edit my question after I tested it with browserity. Thanks the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about symlinking your project directory under `node_modules` (e.g. as `node_modules/project`) and requiring like `require("project/project.my.module.js")`?